# Can I set the width and height of an entire browser window in the code of the same html file?

Tags: html, css, browser, window

I would like to set the size (width and height) of an entire html window page  without a Javascript/css call in another page. I would like the properties in the same html file to control the size of the browser.. Below is what I did to control the size of the browser window, but it didn't work... Help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">

html
{height: 500px;
width:500px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
    }
    body
    {height: 500px;
width:500px; margin:0;
overflow: hidden;
padding:0;  
        }
        .container
        {height: 500px;
width:500px; margin:0;
overflow: hidden;
padding:0;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">This is it.</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Having a hard time following you. Stackoverflow is here to help you solve your programming questions, so you should show us what you have tried first.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can have CSS in the header of your HTML (inside a <style> tag) so you won't have to call CSS in another page.